# Model suggestion for classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification

I have data in below format.

img1 class1|class2|class3

img2 class1|class2

img3 class4

Can someone suggest best model for clasifying this data.

Comment: Please let me know more specific what do you want to do. I mean, do you want to classify image as 4 classes problem? If you want to do that, you need to modify labeling first to get a specific label to the data. I mean img1 has 3 label, img 2 has 2 label now.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can do multi-class multi-label classification by using sigmoid instead of softmax at the last layer.

For example last layer will have 1 nodes for  each class giving the probability of that class.

Assume 5 class add Dense(5, activation="sigmoid") as the last. Ground truth for the first image "img1" will be [1,1,1,0,0] and "img3" will be [0,0,0,1,0].

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a problem specific.

If you want to classify img1 as class 1, 2 and 3 together, you can redefine label that include 3 classes as an class.

For example, `class A` include class 1, 2, and 3.

`class B` include class 1 and 2.

Additionally, you have 4 classes more.

> [class 1, class 2, class 3, class 4]

Now, your dataset are consisted of 6 classes.

> [class 1, class 2, class 3, class 4, class A, class B]

You can solve it as 6 class-classification.